# Inconsistent execution of Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which is running quite inconsistently. First it failed every time it gets called for the first time after a period of rest and the error it throws is always ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT. Initially I thought it might have to do with cold start so I decided to set initially one dedicated instance for it. After that it failed again but less often. So then I increased the dedicated count to 2. But then it failed again. I am not sure if cold start has anything to do with. Below is the cloud function in question:

```
exports.onUpdateCount = functions.runWith({
  // Keep 1 instances warm for this latency-critical function
  minInstances: 2,
}).https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  setCorsHeaders(request, response);

  if (request.method !== "POST") {
    response.send(405).send("HTTP Method " + request.method + " not allowed");
  }
  if (request.get("content-type") !== "application/json") {
    response
      .status(400)
      .send(request.get("content-type") + " content-type not supported");
  }

  try {
    functions.logger.info("received reqeust: ", request.body);
    const { increment, decrement } = request.body;

    functions.logger.log(increment);
    functions.logger.log(decrement);

    if (increment?.length) {
      //do increment object values here
      increment.forEach(async (person) => {
        await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("access")
          .doc(person.accessId)
          .update(createAccessUpdateObject(person.actions, 1));
        functions.logger.log("Calling increment on " + person.accessId);
      });
    }

    if (decrement?.length) {
      // do decrement object values here
      decrement.forEach(async (person) => {
        await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("access")
          .doc(person.accessId)
          .update(createAccessUpdateObject(person.actions, -1));
        functions.logger.log("Calling decrement on " + person.accessId);
      });
    }

    response.status(200).send("Request successful");
  } catch (e) {
    functions.logger.error("Error : ", error);
  }
});

const createAccessUpdateObject = (accessProperties, value) => {
  let response = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < accessProperties.length; i++) {
    response[accessProperties[i]] = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(value);
  }
  console.log(response);
  return response;
};
```

Below the code for the setCORS function:

```
function setCorsHeaders(req, res) {
  let originUrl = "https://flydocs-cloud-production.firebaseapp.com";
  functions.logger.info("Request origin: ", req.headers.origin);
  if (ALLOWED_ORIGINS.includes(req.headers.origin)) {
    originUrl = req.headers.origin;
  }

  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", originUrl);
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Bearer, Content-Type");
    res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    res.status(204).send("");
  }
}
```

Below is one of the error log:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:133:12)
    at /workspace/index.js:853:14
    at cloudFunction (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:50:16)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:97:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:96:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:173:15)
    at sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:38:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:92:44)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:245:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:96:32)
```

I am quite new to using Firebase cloud functions so therefore it will be great if someone can be help me figure what is causing this and how can I ensure that the cloud function always executes as it is quite business critical. I have couple of more functions which are throwing the same error so if I can figure what is causing this then probably I can resolve other errors as well. The functions are using Node 14 runtime. Please let me know in case I forgot to add any other additional information.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This code is not complete.  We can't see what setCorsHeaders does.  Also, await inside of a forEach lambda is not going to work the way you expect.  It is not actually blocking the progress of the iteration.  If you do some debugging, you'll see that forEach retursn before any of the async work is complete.

Comment: Can't say this will help for certain, but whenever you send a response, i.e. in the method and content-type checks, `return` the response instead of letting the conditional chain continue. At that point there's no reason for the function to continue.

Comment: @DougStevenson setCorsHeader is just checking if the request is coming from the domains that are allowed. I have added it in the code. Regarding your second point, as far as I see the function is failing even before getting to that forEach part. It is failing before the try catch block.

Comment: I might have found the issue. I just saw that there was mistake in the code. In line 7, within the function where I am checking if request type is not "POST", I was doing response.send(405).send("HTTP Method " + request.method + " not allowed"). And I think this was causing the function to fail prematurely. I have fixed the error and deployed the function again. Will keep you guys posted if this does fix the issue. Apologies for any inconvenience.

Comment: So in the end, I ended up facing the issue again and again. Eventually I realised that the error is being caused in the setcors function. So I instead used the cors middleware and that has seemed to solved the problem. Thanks a lot.